# VBA sub procedure stopping with no error when VBE isn't open

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a Sub procedure that is triggered on a button press that does the following:

- Prompts the user for a file that is used to filter data
- Verifies the file is in the correct format to filter said data
- Clones the file the Sub is being run from
- Filters the data in the cloned file according to the file that was given

It all works as expected (executes the above four points) when the VBA window is open. When I try to run it with the window closed, it unexpectedly stops working. No errors are thrown, and nothing is caught by my error handler. It just stops.

I *think* I've tracked down the general location this is coming from:

```
Function CloneAndCleanFile(fileToCopy As Workbook, pathOfNewFile As String) As Workbook
    On Error GoTo CloneAndCleanHandler
    
    fileToCopy.SaveCopyAs (pathOfNewFile )
    Dim wkbk As Workbook
    Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open(pathOfNewFile )
    wkbk.Windows(1).Visible = False
        
    If WorksheetExists("Sheet1", wkbk) Then
         wkbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
    End If
    ' code execution stops here, though it successfully deletes Sheet1 from the cloned file
    If WorksheetExists("Sheet2", wkbk) Then
         wkbk.Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
    End If
    
    'clear data from input tab
    Dim inputSheet As Worksheet
    Set inputSheet = wkbk.Sheets("INPUT")
    Dim tmpRow As Integer
    With inputSheet
        tmpRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    inputSheet.Range("A2:E" & tmpRow).Clear
    wkbk.Save
    inputSheet.Unprotect
    Set CloneAndCleanFile = wkbk
    Exit Function
    
CloneAndCleanHandler:
        Title = "Error in Marker Sub"
        Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " & Err.Source & Chr(13) & Err.Description
        MsgBox Msg, , Title, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
        Set CloneAndCleanFile = Nothing
End Function
```

The `WorksheetExists` function is as follows.

```
' checks if a worksheet with name shtName exists in wb
Function WorksheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
        Dim sht As Worksheet

        If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        On Error Resume Next
        Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        WorksheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function
```

Another thing to note - when I run this with the VBA console open, it prompts me to enable macros on the `SaveCopyAs` line. It does not prompt this when the console is closed. Maybe this is keeping it from continuing? Though I haven't been able to find why it isn't giving that prompt when the developer window is closed.

Comment: Please define what **"all works as expected" means**... What do you name "developer window"? Do you mean VBE (Visual Basic Editor)?  How "WorksheetExists" function does look? So,  prompting "to enable macros on the SaveCopyAs" means "all works as expected"... Is this understanding true?

Comment: If you delete a sheet typically you would disable the "are you sure you want to delete this sheet?" using `Displayalerts = False`.  Are you missing the dialog because you hid the window?  Try not hiding it.  Also you seem to have a couple of typos in that code ("Shee1" and "path" vs. "pathOfNewFile") so is this maybe not your actual code but an edited version?

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks for the follow up questions. I've updated the question some. "Works as expected" means that it performs the four bullet points listed, generating clones of the original file with the data filtered according to the supplied input. I don't know if the Enable Macros Prompt is required for the program to work as expected, I just noticed that the prompt does not appear when the VBE is closed.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the questions. I have tried setting `DisplayAlerts = False`. This causes the "Are you sure you want to delete this sheet" prompt to appear, but it does not cause the Enable Macros prompt to appear. Clicking "Delete" on the prompt still causes the application to stop running at the same location. I've corrected my typos; yes, this is an edited version to make variable names a bit more generic.

Comment: `DisplayAlerts = False` should cause the delete prompt to *not* appear, so something is odd about what you're seeing.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm sorry, I'm doing too many things at once. When `DisplayAlerts = False`, neither the delete prompt nor the Enable Macros prompt appear. When `DisplayAlerts = True`, the delete prmopt appears, but the Enable Macros prompt does not. Neither option makes a difference in the program working.

Comment: In that case sounds like `DisplayAlerts = False` should fix the problem?

Comment: No, my point was that I don't think `DisplayAlerts` is related to the problem. Regardless of what the value is set to, the program fails at the same spot.

Comment: Maybe try making sure you have no add-ins which might causing this.  After that I'm out of suggestions.